# "error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant"

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I couldn't find a solution to this error that seemed to match
I'm very new to arduino and am trying to make a set of 5 LEDs light up as the potentiometer

I'm editing the ifstatementconditional example sketch to achieve this but keep getting this error

here's the code

```
// These constants won't change:
const int analogPin = A1;   
const int ledPins[5] = {
  13, 12, 11, 10, 9 };
const int threshold = 1023;   
const int section = threshold / 5; 
const int pinCount = 5

void setup() {
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++)  {
    pinMode(ledPins[thisPin], OUTPUT);      
  }
  // initialize serial communications:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
// read the value of the potentiometer:
int analogValue = analogRead(analogPin);

// if the analog value is high enough, turn on the LED:
if (analogValue > section * 1) {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], HIGH);
} 
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], LOW);
}

if (analogValue > section * 2) {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[1], HIGH);
} 
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPins[1], LOW);
}

if (analogValue > section * 3) {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[2], HIGH);
} 
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPins[2], LOW);
}

if (analogValue > section * 4) {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[3], HIGH);
} 
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPins[3], LOW);
}

if (analogValue > section * 5) {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[4], HIGH);
} 
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPins[4], LOW);
}



// print the analog value:
Serial.println(analogValue);
delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Comment: The error message probably contains a line number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the missing semicolon at

```
  const int pinCount = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the

`const int ledPins[5] = {
  13, 12, 11, 10, 9 };`

just take the 5 out

`const int ledPins[] = {
  13, 12, 11, 10, 9 };`

In C you can't specify the size of an array in the declaration and give it default values. If you wanted to reserve size for an array you later modify you could use

`int foo[5];`

Comment: ah, I meant to remove that in this post
I put it in as an attempt to fix it since I saw a similar thing doing that